# Many to Many is creating new record everytime, code first, EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This issue is driving me crazy. I know it has been asked before and I have tried all those solutions. I know I am doing something wrong but I am unable to find it where.

I have the following model:

```
 public class User : UserEntityBase
{
  /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets roles.
        /// </summary>
        public ICollection<SecurityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I have an another Model for roles:

```
 public class SecurityRole : EntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

The Mappings are set as:

```
HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r=>r.Users).Map(m=>m.ToTable("securityuserroles").MapLeftKey("UserID").MapRightKey("RoleID"));
```

I want to insert new user with the security role called "Everyone".
I am using Domain Service > Repository model.

In User Domain Service Insert Method I have the following code:

```
 var everyonerole = _roleService.Get(rol => rol.Name.Equals(SystemRoleTypes.Everyone.ToString())).SingleOrDefault();




if (everyonerole != null)
            {
                entity.Roles = new List<SecurityRole>();
                entity.Roles.Add(everyonerole);
            }

            base.Insert(entity, out message);
```

By running insert, it is inserting a record in:

User , as well as SecurityRole Table.
Then it create a relation in securityuserroles.

I understand why it is doing due to "Detach behaviour". However, I am getting a role object from database and directly adding into the system.

Please help.

Comment: Are both queries running on the same context instance?  e.g. is your `roleService.Get()` using a different instance than your `base.Insert`

Comment: yes both are using same context instances given by NInject

Comment: and your `Get()` isn't using `AsNoTracking()`?

Comment: I am using code first so I don't think I am calling AsNoTracking().ToList() anywhere...

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: might need to see your context creation and repositories